# Why is my solidity constructor expecting two variables that aren't specified in the parameters?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I am using solidity 0.5.0 My smart contract is expecting two variables in the constructor that aren't in the constructor. rate and wallet. This is my smart contract

```
contract Crowdsale is Owned{
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    // The token being sold
    IERC20 _token;

    // Address where funds are collected
    // How many token units a buyer gets per wei.
    // The rate is the conversion between wei and the smallest and indivisible token unit.
    // So, if you are using a rate of 1 with a ERC20Detailed token with 3 decimals called TOK
    // 1 wei will give you 1 unit, or 0.001 TOK.
    uint256 rate;

    // Amount of wei raised
    uint256 _weiRaised;
    bool status;  
    address payable wallet;

    /**
     * Event for token purchase logging
     * @param purchaser who paid for the tokens
     * @param beneficiary who got the tokens
     * @param value weis paid for purchase
     * @param amount amount of tokens purchased
     */
    event TokensPurchased(address purchaser, address beneficiary, uint256 value, uint256 amount);

    /**
     * @param rate Number of token units a buyer gets per wei
     * @dev The rate is the conversion between wei and the smallest and indivisible
     * token unit. So, if you are using a rate of 1 with a ERC20Detailed token
     * with 3 decimals called TOK, 1 wei will give you 1 unit, or 0.001 TOK.
     * @param wallet Address where collected funds will be forwarded to
     * @param token Address of the token being sold
     */
    constructor (IERC20 token) public {
        rate = 100;
        _token = token;
    //    address payable token = Token();
        wallet = 0x64eCe92B79b096c2771131870C6b7EBAE8C2bd7E;
        status = true;
    }
```

This is the error I keep getting

```
DocstringParsingError: Documented parameter "rate" not found in the parameter list of the function.
,DocstringParsingError: Documented parameter "wallet" not found in the parameter list of the function.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor takes only one parameter - `token`. But your docstring describes two additional parameters - `rate` and `wallet`:

```
 * @param rate Number of token units a buyer gets per wei
```

```
 * @param wallet Address where collected funds will be forwarded to
```

---

You need to remove them from the list of params specified in the Docstring. I.e. remove the lines or mark them as a regular comment - but not use the `@param` keyword.